# CakePHP how to make webroot/js be writable

Tags: cakephp, chmod

Creating a cache file with writeBuffer() requires that webroot/js be world writable and allows a browser to cache generated script resources for any page.

how to make webroot/js be writable and allows a browser .....

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean, CHMOD 775 permissions? As that would allow your webserver to write into the folder.

Here is some further info, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod